# Unable to run powershell command within Windows cmd prompt

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I need to run below powershell command using Windows cmd.exe. The powershell command works fine, when run directly within powershell.exe.

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -like 'ABC.*' } | Stop-Process
```

However, when I run it in cmd mode, I get below error.

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -like 'ABC.*' } | Stop-Process"
```

Error:

```
.Name : The term '.Name' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:30
+ Get-Process | Where-Object { .Name -like 'ABC.*' } | Stop-Process
+                              ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.Name:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Somehow, its not able to use the $_ in the script. I tried adding \ escape character just for $, just for _ and for both. But it resulted in same error. Also tried using old format $PSItem and that also did not work.

Unfortunately, I cannot use a script file for the ps script. Hence need to somehow get this working. Please suggest how can this powershell command be run under cmd.

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `Get-Process | Where-Object Name -like ABC.* | Stop-Process` instead?

Comment: Remove `-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted`. You do not ever need to configure/set an execution policy with a command, _(it is only for running PowerShell scripts)_.